# Git checkout - how do I not lose changes in working directory?

Tags: git

I created a new branch and did a checkout. But my working directory as not clean (changes in working directory have not been committed) at the time so I got the output:

```
D       src/abstracts/media/tea-background.png
M       src/actions/actionTypes.js
M       src/actions/customerActions.js
M       src/actions/deliveryActions.js
```

I am not sure how to go from here ... I do not want to loose the changes that I have made to these files. I am a little scared to run `git commit` or to checkout the master again.

How do I return to the master and commit these changes?

Comment: could you give us the exact commands you ran?

Comment: git checkout <<branch_name>>

Comment: Stash your changes

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you were on `master` branch and you had those (uncommitted) changes, then you ran

```
git branch new-branch # create branch
git checkout new-branch
```

in this case you are still on the exact same commit as `master`. Both `master` and `new-branch` point to the same commit. You can safely run

```
git checkout master
```

to commit your changes.

Most `git` commands make sure you don't loose your files/changes, unless you use `--hard`, `--force` or similar options.

If you want to see where you are in the git history, I would recommend this command:

```
git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate
```

Answer (score 1):

The output of `git status` here above is the result of the comparison git makes between the current state of the working directory and `HEAD`.

Since you've changed where `HEAD` is pointing with `git checkout`, the list might indeed be different. But your changes are still here and git is made to avoid data loss as much as possible. If a checkout would result in wiping some changes in the working dir, it complains with a message and doesn't proceed, to let you handle the situation manually.

You can just `git checkout master` again and you'll find yourself in your initial situation, with your changes preserved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, When creating a new branch with local changes existed, I will use `git stash save 'some message'`, and then using `git branch new-branch # create branch`, last but not least, using `git stash apply 'some message'` or `git pop` to apply your local changes, then with the noraml procedure `git commit -m 'XXX'` to commit your changed files.